# Can Reverse Flash kill Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

Can Reverse Flash kill Flash? Does that mean they can kill each other at **any** time?
 Or is there some particular time point, before which they can't irreversibly damage one another.

Is this time related to a "Missing Flash" newspaper?

Comment: Honestly, Reverse-Flash never wanted to kill Flash so much as earn his respect. He originally wanted to be his best friend, then failing that, he wanted to replace him and be "a better Flash". Of course, he's completely psychotic so the harder he tries, the worse he makes it.

Comment: Can Reverse-Reverse-Flash unkill Reverse-Flash if he's killed by the Flash?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Reverse Flash can kill the Flash, but he does not want to.  After the Reverse Flash was stranded in the past, he had to switch gears.  His plan was to kill a young Barry Allen, but he failed and found himself unable to use his speed to return to his era.  As such, his priorities shifted from killing Barry to nurturing him into a Flash that can then be harnessed to fuel the Reverse Flash's speed.  This then would enable the Reverse Flash to return to his own time.

Another one of his priorities seems to also be a careful maintenance of the timeline, Reverse Flash needs some events in the future to still occur, likely to ensure that his era is as he left it.  Why/how killing young Barry was compatible with that is a mystery.

Comment: Here's a theory: He never wanted to kill young Barry. Older Barry went back in time to save his mom, and Thawne was trying to stop him since that would mess up the timeline. When he said he intended to kill Barry, he meant the one from the future, not little kid Barry. Thawne was actually the hero... and Barry was the villain.

Comment: @Omegacron Except we know what would have happened if they didn't go back.  Nora wouldn't have died, and the particle accelerator accident would have happened in 2020.

Comment: for all we know, a common burglar could have killed her the "first" time, and never gotten caught. same result.

Comment: My understanding was that he developed an interest in maintaining the timeline *after* he failed to kill Barry, during his time being stuck in the past.  He had a lot of time to reflect, and he likely realized how catastrophic his original plan would have been.

Answer (score 9):

**No. Well, Reverse-Flash can't kill Young-Flash at any time.**

The Reverse-Flash apparently needs Young-Barry to not only *become* the Flash, but to achieve some sort of level with his powers. This is why Wells has been training Barry to run faster. This is likely because of the Speed Force which the Reverse-Flash currently has access to. If Barry does not become the Flash or achieve full use of his powers, it would potentially create a paradox where the Reverse-Flash also never gained his own powers.

Backing this up is Reverse-Flash's conversation with Eddie, where Eddie deduces that Reverse-Flash didn't kill him back in December due to their connection. Reverse-Flash states that Eddie is his "insurance". If anything were to happen to Eddie in the upcoming battles, the Reverse-Flash would likely cease to exist.

Reverse-Flash could, however, kill the Flash from the future at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Well i see that the other guy have covered the could he kill the flash part nicely however is it related to the event in 2024?
short answer: not really.

Long Answer: In the comics the Barry Allen dies trying to stop anti monitor universe no actually a multiverse eating being who has eaten thousands of universe becoming stronger after each one. So that would be the writers plan if they make it to season ten they then would kill of Barry and wally west would take over as the flash. In the comics wally west is hit by an anti matter beam which reduces his speed down to the speed of sound but it takes away his pain in running.